# Flutter save PageView position on Back from opened screen with Navigator

Tags: flutter, dart

in below code i try to save `PageView` index when i back from navigate to another screen, but page position switched into `zero` not last index and i can't fix that:

```dart
class _Home extends State<Home> with TickerProviderStateMixin, AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<Home> {
  HomeViewModel _homeVm;
  ScrollController _scrollController;
  PageController _pageController;
  Preference<int> _pageViewIndex;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    _pageViewIndex = Provider.of<ApplicationSettings>(context).pageViewIndex;

    _homeVm = Provider.of<HomeViewModel>(context);
    _homeVm.getMainPagePosts();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController = ScrollController();

    _pageController = PageController(
      initialPage: _pageViewIndex?.getValue() ?? 0,
      keepPage: true,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PreferenceBuilder(
      preference: _pageViewIndex,
      builder: (context, int index) {
        return Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: SafeArea(
            child: ValueListenableBuilder<int>(
                valueListenable: _scrollController.bottomNavigationBar.tabNotifier,
                builder: (context, int tabIndex, child) {
                  _pageViewIndex.setValue(tabIndex);
                  if (_scrollController.hasClients) {
                    _pageController.jumpToPage(_pageViewIndex.getValue());
                  }
                  return Scaffold(
                    ...
                    body: Observer(
                      builder: (context) {
                        if (_homeVm.homeLoading == HomeLoading.loading) {
                          ...
                        } else if (_homeVm.homeLoading == HomeLoading.done && _homeVm.homePageData == HomePageData.loaded) {
                          return PageView(
                            controller: _pageController,
                            onPageChanged: (index) => _pageViewIndex.setValue(index),
                            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                            children: [
                              PageHomeList(
                                lists: _homeVm.products,
                                scrollController: _scrollController,
                              ),
                              PageCategories(categories: _homeVm.categories, scrollController: _scrollController),
                              PageSearch(scrollController: _scrollController)
                            ],
                          );
                        } else if (_homeVm.homeLoading == HomeLoading.done && _homeVm.homePageData == HomePageData.error) {
                          ...
                        } else {
                          ...
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                    ...
                  );
                }),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

navigate to screens:

```dart
InkWell(
  onTap: () => Routes.sailor.navigate(
    '/showProduct',
    params: {
      'categoryId': categories[index].id,
      'categoryName': categories[index].name,
    },
  ),

  ...
)
```

Sailor implementation:

```dart
SailorRoute(
    name: "/showProduct",
    builder: (context, args, params) {
      return ShowProduct(
        categoryId: params.param<int>('categoryId'),
        categoryName: params.param<String>('categoryName'),
      );
    },
    params: [
      SailorParam<int>(name: 'categoryId', isRequired: false),
      SailorParam<String>(name: 'categoryName', isRequired: false),
    ],
    defaultTransitions: [
      SailorTransition.fade_in,
    ],
    defaultTransitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100)),
```

Comment: You are using `initialPage`

Comment: if you are not replacing the screen while navigating to another screen and coming back then it doesn't need any keepAliveMixin, please post the code where you are navigating from and to

Comment: @MohammedAlfateh by default when i remove that, i have the same issue

Comment: @Yadu i dont replace new screen and i use `Sailor` library to navigate new screen, i updated post

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with sailor, therefore i dont know its features,
but `AutomaticKeepAliveMixin`need you to call `super.build(context)` to maintain the state, I see you forgot that, add this as a first line in your build method.

Answer (score 0):

If you had saved the page index then you need to initialize the  `_pageController` also in `didChangeDependencies` after getting the page index from the provider since `initState` is called before `didChangeDependencies` which means the `_pageViewIndex` is still null when you assigned to the `_pageController` so you well end up with 0.

```
@override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    _pageViewIndex = Provider.of<ApplicationSettings>(context).pageViewIndex;
    _pageController = PageController(
      initialPage: _pageViewIndex ?? 0,
      keepPage: true,
    );
  }
```

If `Provider.of<ApplicationSettings>(context).pageViewIndex` is Future you need to a wait it.